# SignalR with Flot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, charts, flot, signalr

I'm considering using SignalR to keep persistent (COMET) connections with my .Net server in a project where I need to update a client-side graph. I'm considering Flot of the graphing portion, but am curious how possible it is to display a "live graph" in this manner. Is Flot a good choice for this? I would like the server to be able to push new data to the graph and have it append to the existing data, as it becomes available.

I haven't found any examples of doing this, so am wondering if there is some difficulty in doing this that I am not anticipating.

Comment: Also, if another graphing option would work better, I'd like to hear about it. I'd prefer to use open source, as I'm likely to need to customize it at least some.

Answer (score 2):

Flot and Highcharts, the two I'm most familiar with, let you redraw the data as long as the axes and grid stay the same.  They are pretty efficient in that case.

To use flot to append data to a continuous graph, you will end up just redrawing the whole graph all the time.  In any modern browser (heck, even IE7), as long as you keep the number of points reasonable, the performance will be totally acceptable.  I have pages with 4-6 flot graphs, updating every second, each having ~3-5 datapoints per second, with up to 5 minutes of data (so ~1000 datapoints per graph, 4000 points in total on the page).  This is achieved with no lag, even on a low-powered machine.

I have not seen any libraries for managing this type of thing over top of flot, so I ended up doing my own caching.

I think the only "gotcha" you'll run into is making sure you don't let your memory usage run out of control.  The first couple attempts I made at this, if you left the graph running overnight, you would come back to 4GB of memory used.  Make sure you properly remove old data, and don't keep references to replaced graphs and AJAX requests.